# How can you round only 2 of the corners on a Xamarin.iOS UITableView?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm developing an iPad app using the current version of Xamarin.iOS with C# and am trying to create a `UITableView` that has only two of it's corners (top right and bottom right) rounded. I know how get all the corners rounded by setting the `myTable.Layer.CornerRadius = 6f;` but don't know how to only round two of them. I've looked around SO but can only see answers for Objective-C. This is what I have currently:

```
    private UIView GetModalRowHeaderView2(RectangleF bounds)
    {
        UIView view = new UIView(bounds);
        view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

        string[] tableItems = new string[] {"Item One","Item Two","Item Three"};

        UITableView myTable = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 20, bounds.Width, bounds.Height - 40), UITableViewStyle.Plain);
        myTable.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
        myTable.ScrollEnabled = false;
        myTable.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);

        // Rounds all corners
        myTable.Layer.CornerRadius = 6f;

        view.Add(myTable);

        return view;
    }
```

Any ideas how I can change this to only round two of the corners?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 11, there is a new property called :

For example 3 gives me both top corners round

```
view.Layer.MaskedCorners = (CoreAnimation.CACornerMask)3;
view.Layer.CornerRadius = 15f;
```

- 0: no rounded corners
- 1: top left
- 2: top right
- 3: top left & right (both top corners)
- 4: bottom left
- 5: top & bottom left (both left corners)
- 6: top right & bottom left
- 7: top left & right, bottom left (all corners except bottom right)
- 8: bottom right
- 9: top left, bottom right
- 10: top & bottom right (both right corners)
- 11: both top corners, bottom right (all corners except bottom left)
- 12: bottom left & right (both bottom corners)
- 13: bottom left & right, top left (all corners except top right)
- 14: bottom left & right, top right (all corners except top left)
- 15: all corners rounded

Comment: Simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to work with masking layers. In my Github repo I have Xamarin.iOS code for a [rectangular view with rounded corners](https://github.com/Krumelur/RoundedRectView). You can use this as a start.

Excerpt from the code:

```
UIBezierPath maskPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect (this.Bounds, this.eRoundedCorners, new SizeF (this.fCornerRadius, this.fCornerRadius));

CAShapeLayer maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer ();
maskLayer.Frame = this.Bounds;
maskLayer.Path = maskPath.CGPath;

// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
this.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: Thanks @Krumelur ... I'll go check it out